# using bot command for dicts

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so basically i want to make a command that can get me the category i want with out hard coding everyone of them, 
so i came onto the code below but (as far as i understand it) the **arg** gets qoutes around it like `(Dict['test1'])` which throws an exception

this is the code:

```
Dict = {
  test1: ["test1-1", "test1-2"],
  test2: ["test2-1", "test2-2"]
}

@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send(Dict["{}".format(arg)]) # if *arg* = *test1* then this will be *Dict['test1']* instead of *Dict[test1]*
```

this is the exception i get:

```
Ignoring exception in command test1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 294, in test1
    reactionRolesDict["{}".format(arg)]
KeyError: 'test1'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'test1'
```

Comment: ```test1``` and not ```'test1'``` there are no quotes after the ```test1``` key in the dictionary

Comment: yes, but if i type in discord `$foo test1` then the bot will take `test1` and replace it with `arg`  but `arg` is in `[]` so since `test1` is a string (as far as i understand), so it will make it `['test1']`

Comment: @user16634524 then ask if args is "test1" then do it on test1

Comment: you mean something like `if arg == 'test1': Dict[test1]`, this works but i would prefer if it wasn't hard coded like that